# OnPropertyChange does not update binding if not creating new instance of binding object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have had some problems with data bindings in WPF, so I have been playing around to try to figure out what is going on. But I ran into something that I do not understand, and I hope someone could explain it to me. The code below is not anything I'm trying to use, it is only for testing.

I have a simple class "Lamp" with only one string property "Name". I also override ToString(), so that it returns the name.

In a "ViewModel" class I create a "Lamp" property and a ICommand:

```
class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        private Lamp _lamp1;

        public Lamp Lamp1
        {
            get { return _lamp1; }
            set { _lamp1 = value; }// OnPropertyChanged("Lamp1"); }
        }

        public ICommand Lamp_click { get { return new RelayCommand(param => LampClickExecute(param)); } }


        public ViewModel()
        {
            Lamp1 = new Lamp() { Name = "Test" };
        }

        private void LampClickExecute(object param)
        {
            var name = Lamp1.Name + "I";

            //HERE IS THE QUESTION!
            //Lamp1 = new Lamp() { Name = name };
            Lamp1.Name = name;

            OnPropertyChanged("Lamp1");
        }
}
```

In the view, I only have a button that binds to the command, and a label that I'm binding to Lamp1:

```
        <Button x:Name="btn_lamp" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="859,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Command="{Binding Path= Lamp_click}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Lamp1 }"/>
        <Label Content= "{Binding Lamp1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="797,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

If I in the command create a new instance of "Lamp" with a new name and call OnPropertyChanged (still in the command, it is commented away in the setter) everything is fine and the new value is shown in the view. But if I do not create a new instance, instead just changing the name of the current one, the view is not updated. I have put a breakpoint in the command to see that everytime the button is clicked, there is an "I" added to the name, nothing strange there.

What is going on behind the scenes here? Is it somehow required that the setter is called, eventhough OnPropertyChanged is called in the command?

As I said, I'm not trying to acheive anyhting specific with this code, just want this behaviour explained.

UPDATE:

My ViewModelBase looks like this:

```
class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: In addition to Jorge Guerrero's answer, you might try adding the following to your `Lamp1` binding in XAML, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the INotifyPropertyChanged and add the code to your ViewModelBase class to update any object on the View.

```
{
    public class ViewModelBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
            [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
            Action onChanged = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;

            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then your code should call the OnPropertyChanged

```
public Lamp Lamp1
        {
            get { return _lamp1; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _lamp1, value; }
        }
```

Comment: My ViewModelBase is simpler than this, but it implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and as I said, the view is updated if I set a new instance to Lamp1. So I think I got that part right? In your version I see that there is a comparison to the old value, but I do not have anything of the kind, and still, the value is not updated without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not changing the property `Lamp1`.  You are changing the property in the lamp class `Name`.  If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in you lamp class with the `Name` field it will update.  With your current code if you changed `Lamp1` to a new instance of `Lamp` with a different name then it would record the change because you are changing the `Lamp1` field.

```
public class Lamp : NotifyChange {  //NotifyChange is the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation in a base class

    private _Name;
    public Name{
        get{ return _Name; }
        set{ 
            if( _Name != value ) {
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged( nameof( Name ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The property change needs to be implemented where the change is happening or it won't know that its changed.  Hope that makes sense why you are not getting the update to show in your view.

Comment: Thanks! So that means that the method bound to the PropertyChangedEventHandler by the Binding, does implement some restrictions on when to update the view? It doesn't simply force an update everytime it is called? Someone here who know why?

Comment: @elg no, it always implements the update it it just depends on where you implement the `ProperyChangedEventHandler` like I stated in my answer.  If you're changing the name them implement it there, or if you are creating new instances of lamp implement it there.